# i want to join every row of a table with another one in a specific order

Tags: sql, join

I have 2 tables :

```
years:
id   name
1    2022
2    2023
3    2024
4    2025
5    2026
```

and months :

```
id   name
1    jan
2    feb
3        mar
```

4    apr
5    jun
6    jul
...

i want to join every row from years to a row from months.
something like this :(with this order)

```
2022 jan
2022 feb
2022 mar
2022 apr
...
2023 jan
2023 feb
....
```

Please help

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here, as you'd tagged 3 completely different products; meaning we have no idea what RDBMS you are really using. Tag spam doesn't help us help you; it makes it harder to. Tagging multiple conflicting tags means that we have no idea what technology you are really asking about, making your question unclear and difficult to answer, and it can easily end up attracting downvotes and also close votes if they make the question unclear. Just tag the technologies you are actually asking about. [Edit] your question to correct your tags.

Comment: I also suggest taking the [tour]. You are yet to do so, and were prompted to when you signed up a year ago. The above "question" comes across as a "give me the codes" demand, rather than a question too; a read of [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) would also be a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's cross join (Cartesian product).

```
select y.name as year,
       m.name as month
from years y cross join months m
order by y.name, m.id
```

Comment: This won't generate the output given in the OP because month short names don't sort chronologically (not my downvote)

Comment: Ah, right, @Tim; wrong sort; fixed, thank you!

Comment: it was my downvote. giving an answer without even having the user share what they tried. or tables or anything to me is not considered helping.  I personally see it as more harmful to the OP than helpful. yes, their problem is solved. but what have they learned out of this?

Comment: thank u so much i didnt give much time to inform myself about cross join ! but i did understand now

Comment: You're welcome. Read about joins, there are various options you can use (not in this particular case; generally speaking).